# HERE-API: Determine direction of crossing streets from adjacent linkID information

Tags: navigation, maps, here-api

I am currently trying to figure out, if for a given route, a street is crossing form the left side or the right side of my route. I got the LinkID Information from the adjacent link. Is there a simple way to determine, in why direction the link is heading from the drivers POV?

Comment: Could you please confirm on the service you are using and also confirm from where you got the Link ID information?

Regards, HERE Support Team

Comment: Dear Customer, Could you please confirm on the service used?